# Refund for medical services never performed

Tags: refund

I scheduled a screening for heart disease with a mobile company 2 days ago.  The cost is $600 which I had to pay up front and used my credit card. I was told at the time of scheduling that if I canceled my refund would be in the form of a gift card. I called to cancel today and was told the refund is a gift card that can only be used to reschedule the screening. Is this legal? Is there anything I can do to get my money back?

Comment: Why are you canceling?

Comment: Charge back and let the credit card company deal with them. "I have received no goods or services."

Comment: Which country and state/province are you in?

Comment: Did they not perform the services as agreed  or did you cancel in advance of the appointment? Why do you think you should get cash back when you agreed to their policy of refunding to a gift card when you booked the appointment?

Comment: A mobile company screening for heart disease? Do they come to your living room and do a cardiogram? Why aren't you getting this done at a hospital?

Comment: Once upon a time, it was clearer that "gift card" meant something specific to the issuer, rather than something more broadly usable like a Visa gift card. You probably should have asked what, exactly, the gift card was for.

Answer (score 10):

1. You agreed to the terms that when you cancelled you would be refunded as a gift card.
2. You cancelled. You got a refund as a gift card. Exactly as stated in the terms.
3. You are surprised by this.

Yes of course it's legal. It's legal for them to refund you nothing if those were the terms you agreed to. Plenty of businesses work on the basis of no refunds.

Is there anything you can do to get your money back? No, but you can rebook the appointment and get the test you paid for.

A chargeback will not work. The company has not "failed to provide the service". They were willing and able to provide the service but you declined it by cancelling the appointment. And presumably they are still willing to provide it at a time of your mutual convenience. If they are not able to reschedule that is a different matter.

If there is a genuine medical reason you don't need the test any more ask nicely if they will refund in full.